# Why my selected option is not selected and result is not displayed. I want to use ajax, jQuery to display the result automatically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to display the selected option automatically and selected option should be selected, but neither the selected option is selected and nor the result is displaying.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled</title>
</head>

<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td width="151">
        <select id="jumpMenu" onChange="MM_jumpMenu(this.value)">
          <option value="">--Select Genre--</option>
          <option value="Action/Mission">Action</option>
          <option value="Racing">Racing</option>
        </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    function MM_jumpMenu(eee){
    var val = document.getElementById("jumpMenu").value;
    if(val=="")
    {
    <?php $abc=mysql_query("select * from games order by game ASC"); ?>
    }
    if(val=="Racing")
    {
    <?php $abc=mysql_query("select * from games where genre='Racing' order by game ASC"); ?>
    }
    if(val=="Action/Mission")
    {
    <?php $abc=mysql_query("select * from games where genre='Action/Mission' order by game ASC"); ?>
    }
});
});
</script>
  <?php
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($abc))
{
?>
    <td><?php echo $row['game']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['genre']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Where is the issue?

Comment: Where is `val` defined, and why you override the passed argument? Why haven't you checked the console?

Comment: Now i have edited but still not working. What to do?

Comment: What the PHP renders to the page? Also notice, that `MM_jumpMenu` is out of scope of HTMLElements, you better to attach the change event using jQuery within `$(document).ready(...)`. You can see an error in the console when selecting a new option, if you just bothered to debug your code...

Comment: i have not shown it in question but in my php i have connected it to musql. <?php
include("db.php");
?>

Comment: you can't run php code in the browser...your code makes no sense at all. A simple look at the final output will show nothing printed within all the javascript `if` conditions

Answer (score 0):

Please bear in mind that `JS` is client-side and `PHP` is server-side. You cannot run the two together as you're trying to do. However, you can use ajax to make a call to the server and run a `PHP` script receive and use the response in `JS`.

Reference: [jQuery.ajax() | jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)